# jQuery: Get position of HTML 5 drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a web application with a tabpane. To move tabs around the tabpane and into other windows I am using native HTML drag and drop.

To move the tabs around the tabpane a user would drag one tab onto another, which will then place it to the left or right depending on where it was dragged on the tab. I am unsure how to find the position the tab was dropped on another tab.

```
$(document).on('dragstart', '.tabpane li', function(e) {
  ...
});

$(document).on('dragover', '.tabpane li', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});

$(document).on('drop', '.tabpane li', function(e) {
  var droppedOnTabAt = ? ? ? ; // How do I find this?

  if (droppedOnTabAt.x > $(this).width() / 2) {
    // move tab to the right of the dropped onto tab
  } else {
    // move tab to the left of the dropped onto tab
  }
});
```

Comment: Inspect the event object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to solve my issue by reading more [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drop).

```
$(document).on('drop', '.tabpane li', function(e) {
  var droppedOnTabAt = e.originalEvent.clientX; // Gets the x position of the drop relative to the window
  var tabMiddlePos = $(this).offset().left + $(this).width() / 2; // Gets the center of width of the tab dropped on relative to the window

  if (droppedOnTabAt > tabMiddlePos ) {
    // move tab to the right of the dropped onto tab
  } else {
    // move tab to the left of the dropped onto tab
  }
});
```